# Выполнение php кода в определенный момент времени

Tags: php, mysql, веб-сервер

Мне допустим в час ночи необходимо обработать все записи одной таблицы в БД. В качестве серверного языка использую php. Как мне установить timeout для выполнения команды или, что нужно сделать, что бы провести данные действия ?) подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если на сервере есть ``cron`` (что скорее всего), то настроить на запуск нужного скрипта в час ночи.

Comment: Чем [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) не устроил?

Comment: Сейчас гляну, возможно устроит, спасибо )

Comment: А PHP-то зачем? или обработка - такая, что не может быть выполнена в рамках MySQL-сервера?

Answer (score 3):

однозначно cron.

Вариант 1

```
0 1 * * * root php -f phpfile.php
```

Нужно указать пути к php и к файлу

Вариант 2

```
0 1 * * * root curl -s -o /dev/null http://site.ru/phpfile.php
```

Если нужно дергать ссылку какую-то.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть крон, используйте его. Если доступа к крону нет, то можно:

1. Использовать MySQL [`EVENTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)
2. Использовать сторонние сервисы, которые взывают ваши скрипты по заданному расписанию. Можно поискать по словосочетанию "cron as a service" или использовать планировщик на локальном компьютере

См. также:

1. [Использование событий MySQL на практике](https://habrahabr.ru/post/123391) / Хабрахабр
2. [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) (официальная документация на английском)

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас нет Крона то создайте аналог cron на php.

Напишите бесконечный цикл и откройте скрипт в браузере, и пока он открыт, цикл с сверкой времени будет работать как планировщик.

```
while()
{

/// проверка текущего времени
$time =date('h');

/// условие если текущее время и заданное совпадут то выполняй код
if($time == 'час ночи')
   {

///действие

   }

}
```

Можно вместо цикла использовать рефреш страницы(к примеру обновление страницы настроить на каждые ~10 минут.

Comment: Зачем цикл можно каждый раз в час ночи обновлять страницу